# Laravel Validation of email and regex not working

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-4, preg-replace

**Problem**

I am trying to validate a form using the Laravel built in validation. I want to make sure that the email only has a .edu in it. However, there Laravel continues to throw a `preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found` error. I heard this has something to do with a pipe delimiter instead of an array one, but I am unsure what this mean / how to fix it. The code I have is below.

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), 
        array(
            'email' => 'Required|Max:50|Email|Unique:users|Regex:/(\.edu(\.[a-z]+)?|\.ac\.[a-z]+)$/',
            'first-name' => 'required|max:20|min:3|',
            'last-name' => 'required|max:30|min:3|',
            'username' => 'required|max:30|min:3|unique:users|',
            'city' => '',
            'state' => '',
            'password-init' => 'required|min:6|AlphaNum',
            'password-check', 'required|min:6|AlphaNum|same:password-init'
        )
    );
```

**Any help would be appreciated**
**Thanks!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using pipes `|` to separate your different validation rules, Laravel gets confused when it sees a pipe in the middle of your Regex. So break up just the "email" rule like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), 
    array(
        'email' => array(
            'required',
            'max:50',
            'email',
            'unique:users',
            'regex:/(\.edu(\.[a-z]+)?|\.ac\.[a-z]+)$/'
        ),
        'first-name' => 'required|max:20|min:3|',
        ...
```

That's what it means when it talks about an array instead of pipes in the doc:
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-regex